# Need to make a mask invoked over a dialog box ignore escape (ExtJS 5.1.2)

Tags: extjs, extjs5

Reason: We need to stop allowing dismissal of the U/I element while we are waiting for a reply from an external device/system. I've tried a number of different approaches (keymap, onEsc). There is already a working listener that dismisses the mask when the external system returns with data. Here is the code as I have it currently...

```
onSaveRecord: function () {
    var me = this;
    .
    .
    .
    if (me.onRecordSaving(recordDetail, isNew)) {
        var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask({
            msg: 'Processing',
            target: me.getView(),
            closable: true,
            onEsc: function () { my.myOnEsc(); }
        });

        myMask.show();
        //me.getView().mask('Processing');
        //
        .
        .
        .
},

myOnEsc: function () {
    debugger; // <--- never hits this 
    Ext.emptyFn();
},
```

Comment: Which browser are you using.Bcoz onEsc works perfectly.Can you please share some fiddle.

Comment: Running on chrome browser I believe. I hope this works for you... https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_ncyYTZrVeqUXpadDFjcDVNeVE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wound up with this in the actualDialogBox.js...

```
onSaveRecordClick: function () {
    var me = this;
    me.callSuper();
    var win1 = me.getView();
    .
    .
    . generic conditional code added 
    . (not pertinent to the escape key disabling).
    .
    if (condition) {
        var win = Ext.WindowManager.getActive();
        win.setDisableEscapeKey(true);
    }
},
```

and in a super of the above dialog...

```
disableEscapeKey: false,

setDisableEscapeKey: function (value) {
    this.disableEscapeKey = value;
},

onEsc: function () {
    var me = this;

    if (me.disableEscapeKey) {
        Ext.emptyFn();
    } else {
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
},
```

Works perfectly for my application.